# upload files to the server

Tags: php

I worked currently on being able to upload files to the web site and it should just hand it over in a folder.

It is such that I have trouble uploading the file and there are no files or other things.

I need to work on later of saving file info into the database with which something that has come into the server etc.

What should be loaded into the server, is mostly pdf and mp3 and zip files and Word (doc files)

I try to do like this

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>Upload</td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="file" class="new"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Materialer</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="materialer" class="new">
                            <?php
                            $materialer = $mebe->materialer();
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>File type</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="materialer" class="new">
                            <?php
                                $file_type = $mebe->file_type();
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="upload_telefon" value="Upload" class="new"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST["upload_telefon"]))
        {
            $upload_file_typer_indhold = $mebe->upload_file_typer_indhold();
        }
        ?>


function upload_file_typer_indhold()
    {

        if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {

            echo "" . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "";

        }
        else
        {

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fil1"]["tmp_name"], "upload/undervisning/");

        }
    }
```

When I tried to upload, it says this:

**This site is not accessible** and it is standing there on the side also.

Comment: Why are you using table?

Comment: Instead of `action="#"`, try using `action="."`.

Comment: @EdHeal I want to make it nice up - bibhas even if I use .htaccess?

Comment: #bibhas I've done it but it works in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use another filename instead of '#':

```
<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>
```